# Updating UITableView from deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to update my `tableView`from deleteRowsAtIndexPaths to use the animation.fade . So please could you tell how I can update the `tableView` while I have two array?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! PlacesTableViewCell
            cell.title.text = placeArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.backgroundImage.image = photoArray[indexPath.row]

            return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("section and row \(indexPath.section) \(indexPath.row) ")

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: add `placeArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` and `photoArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` before `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` in delegate method

Comment: @Akhilrajtr how can I call this commitEditingStyle method if I have a button?

Comment: do you have a button in cell for delete?

Comment: What I have exactly is a textfield and once I start editing the textfield I would update the tableView. @Akhilrajtr

Comment: is the textfield inside tableview cell? when did you delete the row? confused!

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing you. Yes the textfield is in the tableview cell. I want to delete all row when I touch the textfield @Akhilrajtr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86770/discussion-between-can-and-akhilrajtr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  self.placeArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
  self.photoArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
  self.tablename.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

To delete whole section, try this:

```
 self.placeArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
 self.photoArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)                                                           
 self.tablename.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I want to delete the whole array index not only the cell I delete

Comment: Do you mean the whole section in the tableview with deleting the array index?

Comment: Yes, please the whole section

Comment: I have updated my answer for deleting the whole section.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try:`[tableView reloadData];` after eliminating the desired object

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: the author asks how to update the table after you delete a record.
After deleting the record and you can run this command  [tableView reloadData];  to update the table.